# Where can I find the Chasam Sofer's poems?

Tags: song-poetry, authorship, publications, acharonim, chatam-sofer

According to the Jewish Encyclopedia, the Chasam Sofer wrote several poems. Where can I find them? I've been unable to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Mi.Yodeya. I hope you look through the site and find answers to many of your questions.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a link to [Shiras Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/35194) which contains the poems of the Chasam Sofer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have them in english ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is only available in Hebrew.